# From the figure, determine the new coordinates with respect to a new basis

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

> [image: change of basis]
>
> On the figure in the plane, a standard basis $e=(i,j)$ is given and another basis $a=(a_1,a_2).$
>
> 1) A vector $u$ has the coordinates $(5,-1)$ with respect to the basis $e$. Determine the $a$-coordinates of $u$.
>
> 2) A vector $v$ has the coordinates $(-1,-2)$ with respect to basis $a$. Determine the $e$-coordinates of $v$.

This is a new subject for me, and I'm having trouble understanding the concept. How am I meant to approach this?

Comment: For the first one, you want to find $c_1, c_2$ so that $c_1a_1+c_2a_2 = u$. The notation $[u]_{a} = [c_1,c_2]$ is the coordinates of $u$ with respect to the basis $a$. Conceptually, to get to the vector $v$, you want to move $c_1$ units in the $a_1$ direction and move $c_2$ units in the $a_2$ direction.

Comment: @Steve Added a graph showing how the transformation works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the graph you can see that

$$
a_1 = i - 2j ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ a_2 = i + j
$$

which can be solved for $i$ and $j$:

$$
i = \frac{1}{3}a_1 + \frac{2}{3}a_2 ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ j = -\frac{1}{3}a_1 + \frac{1}{3}a_2
$$

1. $(5,-1)_e$

   \begin{eqnarray}
    u = (5,-1)_e &=& 5 i - j = \frac{1}{3}(5(a_1 + 2a_2) - (-a_1 + a_2)) \\
   &=& \frac{1}{3}(6a_1 + 9a_2) = 2a_1 + 3a_2 = (2, 3)_a
    \end{eqnarray}
2. $(-1,-2)_a$

   \begin{eqnarray}
    v = (-1,-2)_a &=& -a_1 -2a_2 = -(i - 2j) - 2(i + j) = -3i \\
   &=& (-3,0)_e
    \end{eqnarray}

**EDIT:**
The figure shows the representation of the vector $u$ (orange) in both basis. It can be seen that indeed $(5,-1)_e = (2, 3)_a$

[image]

Comment: Where did you get $(a_1+2a_2)-(-a_1+a_2)$ from?

Comment: @Steve From the second set of equations $i = (a_1 + 2a_2)/3$ and $j=(-a_1+a_2)/3$

Comment: Alright, thank you. Do you have time to look at my newest question? @caverac

Comment: @Steve Sure, send me the link

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032214/from-the-figure-determine-the-new-coordinates-with-respect-to-a-new-basis/2032228?noredirect=1#comment4172040_2032228 @caverac

Comment: @Steve This is a link to this page

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032436/linear-transformation-in-the-plane?noredirect=1#comment4171826_2032436 @caverac here it is

Comment: @Steve To solve this problem we need more information about then notation, e.g., what does ${_e}M_a$ mean?

Comment: it's the change of basis matrix notation in my country. When in a vector space there is given a basis $e$ and a new basis $b$ is known from its basis vectors' $e$-coordinates, it's possible to write $_eM_a$